# Flask server error 400 Bad Request ...... KeyError: 'file'

Tags: python, flask

I intend to send a video to a flask server with the post request sent from an android application. I get this error

```
werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
KeyError: 'file'
```

Below is the python code for the flask server. Note that I am trying to get the content of the files (MultiDict) for debugging purpose using the for loop. I get no output on the powershell window. Also, since the error is `KeyError: 'file'`, I understand that the files variable is null?

```py
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify

path_upload_folder = 'C:\\Users\\vishw\\Desktop\\cse535a3_uploads\\uploads'

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['path_upload_folder'] = path_upload_folder
@app.route('/mainapp', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_video():
    print('Started')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        keys = request.files.keys()
        for each in keys:
            print(each)
        sent_file = request.files['file']
        sent_file.save(app.config['path_upload_folder'] + '\\' + secure_filename(sent_file.filename))
        return jsonify(operation_status="true")
    return jsonify(operation_status="false")

app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000, debug=True)
```

Here is the relevant code for the android application

```java
public class ExampleGesture extends AppCompatActivity {
    private final int VIDEO_CAPTURE = 1;
    private VideoView example_gesture;
    private boolean captured_video = false;
    private MediaType object_mediatype;
    private Intent intent_record_video;
    private File file_media;
    private String name_file;
    private String gesture_received;
    private String address_server_ipv4;
    private String port_number;
    private String posturl;
    private int count_files = -1;
    private int [] count_practice; //= ((MainApplication)getApplication()).count_practice;
    private HashMap links;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_example_gesture);
//        Log.i("APP: ", getApplication().getClass().getSimpleName());
        Log.i("EG: ", "Under Super");
        Log.i("EXAMACTTHREAD: ", String.valueOf((Thread.currentThread()).getId()));
        Context context_current = getApplicationContext();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
              Log.i("EXAMACTTHREADNEW: ", String.valueOf((Thread.currentThread()).getId()));
//                Log.i("EG: ", "Setting COntent View");
                count_practice = ((MainApplication)getApplication()).count_practice;
                Intent intent_current = getIntent();
                String gesture = intent_current.getStringExtra("EXTRA_GESTURE");
                gesture_received = gesture;
                ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> arrayAdapter_gestures = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(context_current,
                        R.array.list_gestures,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
//              Log.i("ARRAY: ", String.valueOf(arrayAdapter_gestures.getCount()));
                links = new HashMap();
                for (int index = 0; index < arrayAdapter_gestures.getCount(); ++index) {
//                  Log.i("ARRAY: ", (arrayAdapter_gestures.getItem(index)).toString());
                    if (!((arrayAdapter_gestures.getItem(index)).toString().equals("Select Gesture"))) {
                        links.put((arrayAdapter_gestures.getItem(index)).toString(), 0);
                    }
                }
//              Log.i("GESTURE: ", gesture);
                String path_file = "/sdcard/Movies/";
                if (gesture == "FanUp") {
                    path_file = path_file + "H-IncreaseFanSpeed.mp4";
                } else if (gesture == "FanDown") {
                    path_file = path_file + "H-DecreaseFanSpeed.mp4";
                } else path_file = path_file + "H-" + gesture + ".mp4";
                Uri u1 = Uri.fromFile(new File(path_file));
                example_gesture = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView_gesture);
                example_gesture.setVideoURI(u1);
                example_gesture.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg_mp) { example_gesture.start(); }
                });
                example_gesture.start();
                Button button_record = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_record);
                button_record.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg_view) {
                        intent_record_video = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
                        intent_record_video.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 5);
                        File k = new File("/storage/self/primary/DCIM/Camera/");
                        count_files = (k.list()).length;
                        startActivityForResult(intent_record_video, VIDEO_CAPTURE);

                    }
                });
                Button button_previous_screen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_previous_screen);
                button_previous_screen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg_view) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
                    }
                });
                Button button_upload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_upload);
                button_upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg_view) {
                        if (name_file.length() > 0) {
                            RequestBody postbody = RequestBody.create(object_mediatype, file_media);
                            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

                            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                                    .url(posturl)
                                    .post(postbody)
                                    .build();
                            
                            Log.i("REQUEST: ", "Throwing a request");
                            client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(final Call call, final IOException e) {
                                    call.cancel();
                                    Log.i("REQUEST: ", "Call canceled");
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
                                }
                            });
                            name_file = "";
                        }
                    }
                });
                address_server_ipv4 = "192.168.0.113";
                port_number = "5000";
                posturl = "http://" + address_server_ipv4 + ":" + port_number + "/mainapp";
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }).start();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

                Log.i("THREAD: ", "ran the resume thread");
        File file = new File("/storage/self/primary/DCIM/Camera/");
        String[] list_files = file.list();
        if (list_files.length > count_files && count_files != -1) {
            captured_video = true;
            count_files = list_files.length;
        }
        if (!example_gesture.isPlaying()) {
            example_gesture.start();
        }
        if (captured_video) {

//          File file = new File("/storage/self/primary/DCIM/Camera/");
//          String[] list_files = file.list();
            for (int index = 0; index < list_files.length; ++index) {
                if ((list_files[index]).charAt(0) == 'V') {
                    File f = new File(file.getPath() +'/' + list_files[index]);
                    name_file = file.getPath() + '/' + gesture_received
                            + "_PRACTICE_"
                            + count_practice[(int) links.get(gesture_received)] + "_desai.mp4";
                    File f2 = new File(name_file);
                    boolean result = f.renameTo(f2);
                    file_media = f2;
                    ++count_practice[(int) links.get(gesture_received)];
                    break;
                }
            }
            captured_video = false;
            object_mediatype = MediaType.parse("video/mp4");
        }
    }
}
```

As I proposed before, is the files variable in the Request null? I.e the file is not being sent? Also, kindly give your opinion on whether am I sending the video file in a correct way or not. It would be most generous of you to show me the correct way If I am mistaken as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to answer it instantly since assignment deadlines, but you want to focus on the name of the file you are sending in that request and the name you use in the flask program. That's all I can recall right now.

EDIT:
`sent_file = request.files['file']`, here, 'file' should be 'name' of the the information sent in the RequestBody